# Remove shadow in text of a uibutton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I used following codes to customize *text* of a **Customized UIBarButtonItem**:

```
editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
[editButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But the titleText get a little shadow.

How can I remove that shadow?

Comment: can u show a screenshot ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890723/putting-text-shadow-on-a-uibutton-text-label and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178896/adding-a-shadow-to-a-uibutton-label-in-xcode

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084331/how-do-i-disable-the-navigation-bar-shadow-in-ios-6-for-navigation-bars-with-cus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
[editButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0], UITextAttributeFont,

[UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil]

forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893